Observational pre post design and confounder adjustment
I have observational data with baseline, and two follow-up measures with a binary treatment. Dependant variable is questionnaire scale score ***. I am planning on fitting a linear mixed effects model with subject as random effect, treatment x time interaction, and baseline as a covariate, allowing for non linearity using a spline i.e. the ANCOVA type model. My questions are:

Assuming adequate sample size, is it advisable to fit other covariates to adjust for confounding? I’m not certain if the baseline covariate is enough on its own to do that? If the answer is yes, would that include time varying covariates as well as time dependent covariates?

In addition to the above, would fitting a propensity score as a covariate (perhaps as a spline) also be recommended?


*** I am aware that the scale score is an ordinal scale, but I thought it reasonable to first try a linear mixed model and check if the distribution of residuals are appropriately normal.
